# How to config Spring Security with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

I need to add Spring Security into my project. What is the right way to do it? I have to entities User and UserRole and DAO and Services for them. I use EntityManager to access data. I read, that I just need to write implementation for UserDetails, but I don't know how to do it correctly. Here my code:

User.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonProperty
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "username", length = 20, nullable = false)
@JsonProperty
private String username;
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty
private String password;
@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty
private boolean enabled;
@Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty
private String email;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
//getters and setters
```

UserRole.java

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonProperty
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
private User user;

@Column(name="role")
@JsonProperty
private String role;
//getters and setters
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had wrote a blog post about exactly what you are looking for. see this post and I am pretty sure it will answer your question:

https://giannisapi.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/spring-3-spring-security-implementing-custom-userdetails-with-hibernate/

In the Service layer of UserDetails below, pay attention that it implements UserDetailsService from org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService.

and also :

he loadUserByUsername methods return the result of the assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity . Simply put, what this method of the assembler does is to to construct a org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User object from the given UserEntity DTO. The code of the Assembler class is given below: